# Convergent series implication question.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm currently studying random processes and among the many proofs that I've been working my way through I've noticed the following implication is assumed without further justification,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n < \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}{\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}x_n} = 0
\end{equation}

This makes intuitive sense to me, but I don't believe justifying it by claiming it follows from "elementary logic" is sufficient.

I'm guessing that the implication follows directly from some definition of limits or some lemma for convergent series, but I can't figure it out. So what is a formal justification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences, applied to the sequence of partial sums of the series:

For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that
$$ \Big|\sum_{k=n}^mx_k\Big|<\varepsilon $$
for all $m\geq n\geq N$. Fixing $n$ and taking $m\to\infty$ shows that
$$ \Big|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}x_k\Big|\leq \varepsilon $$
for all $n\geq N$, and since $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number it follows that $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}x_k\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you carmichael561. In your first inequality is the $n$ supposed to be $N$?

Comment: nevermind I think it makes sense after reading it more carefully.